# New Debian installation hanged

Tags: linux, debian

I installed a new copy of Debian on my laptop and upgraded it from testing repo. However, when I turn on my laptop, the system stops working. This error that I found in my logs is new for me and I can't find any good solution; every time I install Debian or upgrade it on my laptop this problem happens.

#### dmesg

```
[  362.010297] ntpd            D ffff8802519c9350     0  2267      1 0x00000004
[  362.010302]  ffff8802519c9010 0000000000000082 0000000000014280 0000000000014280
[  362.010307]  ffff880251addfd8 ffff8802519c9010 ffffffff81887b60 ffff880251addc80
[  362.010310]  ffffffff81887b64 ffff8802519c9010 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81887b68
[  362.010314] Call Trace:
[  362.010328]  [<ffffffff814a45d0>] ? schedule_preempt_disabled+0x20/0x70
[  362.010332]  [<ffffffff814a6043>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x133/0x1b0
[  362.010336]  [<ffffffff814a60d6>] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x25
[  362.010343]  [<ffffffff813ccca0>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x10/0x30
[  362.010347]  [<ffffffff813e8d1a>] ? netlink_unicast+0xca/0x1a0
[  362.010351]  [<ffffffff813e910a>] ? netlink_sendmsg+0x31a/0x750
[  362.010357]  [<ffffffff813a8036>] ? sock_sendmsg+0x86/0xc0
[  362.010360]  [<ffffffff813e8301>] ? netlink_insert+0x131/0x220
[  362.010364]  [<ffffffff813a81a1>] ? SYSC_sendto+0xf1/0x180
[  362.010368]  [<ffffffff813a51ea>] ? sock_alloc_file+0x9a/0x130
[  362.010373]  [<ffffffff811950d5>] ? __fd_install+0x15/0x40
[  362.010378]  [<ffffffff814aeb79>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[  362.010382] INFO: task NetworkManager:2486 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  362.010462]       Tainted: G           O 3.13-1-amd64 #1
[  362.010538] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  362.010629] NetworkManager  D ffff88024ff1bb40     0  2486      1 0x00000000
[  362.010633]  ffff88024ff1b800 0000000000000086 0000000000014280 0000000000014280
[  362.010637]  ffff8800373d3fd8 ffff88024ff1b800 ffffffff81887b60 ffff8800373d36f0
[  362.010640]  ffffffff81887b64 ffff88024ff1b800 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81887b68
[  362.010644] Call Trace:
[  362.010648]  [<ffffffff814a45d0>] ? schedule_preempt_disabled+0x20/0x70
[  362.010652]  [<ffffffff814a6043>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x133/0x1b0
[  362.010661]  [<ffffffff814a60d6>] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x25
[  362.010675]  [<ffffffffa06c582a>] ? ieee80211_unregister_hw+0x4a/0x110 [mac80211]
[  362.010683]  [<ffffffffa078f163>] ? brcms_remove+0x43/0x70 [brcmsmac]
[  362.010691]  [<ffffffffa0791181>] ? brcms_ops_start+0x2b1/0x310 [brcmsmac]
[  362.010703]  [<ffffffffa05e9d5b>] ? cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call+0x3db/0x600 [cfg80211]
[  362.010714]  [<ffffffffa06d7ce1>] ? ieee80211_do_open+0x2d1/0xd90 [mac80211]
[  362.010719]  [<ffffffff813c1ae6>] ? __dev_open+0xa6/0x120
[  362.010722]  [<ffffffff813c1da1>] ? __dev_change_flags+0x91/0x160
[  362.010726]  [<ffffffff813c1e8e>] ? dev_change_flags+0x1e/0x60
[  362.010729]  [<ffffffff813cee32>] ? do_setlink+0x312/0x980
[  362.010734]  [<ffffffff81294b7c>] ? __nla_put+0xc/0x20
[  362.010737]  [<ffffffff81294bb8>] ? nla_put+0x28/0x40
[  362.010747]  [<ffffffffa0602940>] ? nl80211_send_wiphy+0x3d0/0x2180 [cfg80211]
[  362.010750]  [<ffffffff81294969>] ? nla_parse+0x29/0xc0
[  362.010754]  [<ffffffff813d00b4>] ? rtnl_newlink+0x394/0x5d0
[  362.010758]  [<ffffffff813e6e3b>] ? netlink_dump+0x11b/0x230
[  362.010762]  [<ffffffff813ccd4e>] ? rtnetlink_rcv_msg+0x8e/0x250
[  362.010766]  [<ffffffff813b5cfe>] ? __skb_recv_datagram+0xfe/0x4c0
[  362.010769]  [<ffffffff813b0703>] ? __alloc_skb+0x43/0x2a0
[  362.010773]  [<ffffffff813cccc0>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x30/0x30
[  362.010776]  [<ffffffff813e96f9>] ? netlink_rcv_skb+0xa9/0xc0
[  362.010780]  [<ffffffff813cccaf>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x1f/0x30
[  362.010783]  [<ffffffff813e8d1a>] ? netlink_unicast+0xca/0x1a0
[  362.010786]  [<ffffffff813e910a>] ? netlink_sendmsg+0x31a/0x750
[  362.010790]  [<ffffffff813a8036>] ? sock_sendmsg+0x86/0xc0
[  362.010794]  [<ffffffff813a7d64>] ? move_addr_to_kernel.part.16+0x14/0x60
[  362.010797]  [<ffffffff813a8843>] ? ___sys_sendmsg+0x3c3/0x3d0
[  362.010801]  [<ffffffff8119fa4d>] ? __inode_wait_for_writeback+0x6d/0xc0
[  362.010808]  [<ffffffff81096f80>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x30/0x30
[  362.010811]  [<ffffffff814aa961>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1d1/0x500
[  362.010818]  [<ffffffff8117b278>] ? __fput+0x148/0x210
[  362.010822]  [<ffffffff813a8eb9>] ? __sys_sendmsg+0x39/0x70
[  362.010826]  [<ffffffff814aeb79>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[  362.010845] INFO: task ifconfig:2765 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  362.010923]       Tainted: G           O 3.13-1-amd64 #1
[  362.011000] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  362.011091] ifconfig        D ffff880252627350     0  2765   2713 0x00000004
[  362.011095]  ffff880252627010 0000000000000082 0000000000014280 0000000000014280
[  362.011099]  ffff880250b13fd8 ffff880252627010 ffffffff81887b60 ffff880250b13df0
[  362.011102]  ffffffff81887b64 ffff880252627010 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81887b68
[  362.011105] Call Trace:
[  362.011110]  [<ffffffff814a45d0>] ? schedule_preempt_disabled+0x20/0x70
[  362.011113]  [<ffffffff814a6043>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x133/0x1b0
[  362.011118]  [<ffffffff81188980>] ? path_openat+0x100/0x670
[  362.011122]  [<ffffffff814a60d6>] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x25
[  362.011125]  [<ffffffff813d3055>] ? dev_ioctl+0x365/0x5d0
[  362.011129]  [<ffffffff813a534d>] ? sock_do_ioctl+0x3d/0x50
[  362.011132]  [<ffffffff813a5798>] ? sock_ioctl+0x1e8/0x2c0
[  362.011136]  [<ffffffff8118b94f>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x2cf/0x4a0
[  362.011139]  [<ffffffff8118bba0>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x80/0xa0
[  362.011143]  [<ffffffff814aeb79>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[  482.058075] INFO: task ntpd:2267 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  482.058169]       Tainted: G           O 3.13-1-amd64 #1
[  482.058244] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  482.058336] ntpd            D ffff8802519c9350     0  2267      1 0x00000004
[  482.058341]  ffff8802519c9010 0000000000000082 0000000000014280 0000000000014280
[  482.058346]  ffff880251addfd8 ffff8802519c9010 ffffffff81887b60 ffff880251addc80
[  482.058352]  ffffffff81887b64 ffff8802519c9010 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81887b68
[  482.058359] Call Trace:
[  482.058373]  [<ffffffff814a45d0>] ? schedule_preempt_disabled+0x20/0x70
[  482.058378]  [<ffffffff814a6043>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x133/0x1b0
[  482.058382]  [<ffffffff814a60d6>] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x25
[  482.058388]  [<ffffffff813ccca0>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x10/0x30
[  482.058393]  [<ffffffff813e8d1a>] ? netlink_unicast+0xca/0x1a0
[  482.058396]  [<ffffffff813e910a>] ? netlink_sendmsg+0x31a/0x750
[  482.058402]  [<ffffffff813a8036>] ? sock_sendmsg+0x86/0xc0
[  482.058405]  [<ffffffff813e8301>] ? netlink_insert+0x131/0x220
[  482.058408]  [<ffffffff813a81a1>] ? SYSC_sendto+0xf1/0x180
[  482.058413]  [<ffffffff813a51ea>] ? sock_alloc_file+0x9a/0x130
[  482.058417]  [<ffffffff811950d5>] ? __fd_install+0x15/0x40
[  482.058423]  [<ffffffff814aeb79>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[  482.058427] INFO: task NetworkManager:2486 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  482.058507]       Tainted: G           O 3.13-1-amd64 #1
[  482.058582] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  482.058672] NetworkManager  D ffff88024ff1bb40     0  2486      1 0x00000000
[  482.058676]  ffff88024ff1b800 0000000000000086 0000000000014280 0000000000014280
[  482.058680]  ffff8800373d3fd8 ffff88024ff1b800 ffffffff81887b60 ffff8800373d36f0
[  482.058683]  ffffffff81887b64 ffff88024ff1b800 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81887b68
[  482.058687] Call Trace:
[  482.058691]  [<ffffffff814a45d0>] ? schedule_preempt_disabled+0x20/0x70
[  482.058695]  [<ffffffff814a6043>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x133/0x1b0
[  482.058705]  [<ffffffff814a60d6>] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x25
[  482.058718]  [<ffffffffa06c582a>] ? ieee80211_unregister_hw+0x4a/0x110 [mac80211]
[  482.058726]  [<ffffffffa078f163>] ? brcms_remove+0x43/0x70 [brcmsmac]
[  482.058733]  [<ffffffffa0791181>] ? brcms_ops_start+0x2b1/0x310 [brcmsmac]
[  482.058744]  [<ffffffffa05e9d5b>] ? cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call+0x3db/0x600 [cfg80211]
[  482.058756]  [<ffffffffa06d7ce1>] ? ieee80211_do_open+0x2d1/0xd90 [mac80211]
[  482.058761]  [<ffffffff813c1ae6>] ? __dev_open+0xa6/0x120
[  482.058764]  [<ffffffff813c1da1>] ? __dev_change_flags+0x91/0x160
[  482.058768]  [<ffffffff813c1e8e>] ? dev_change_flags+0x1e/0x60
[  482.058771]  [<ffffffff813cee32>] ? do_setlink+0x312/0x980
[  482.058776]  [<ffffffff81294b7c>] ? __nla_put+0xc/0x20
[  482.058779]  [<ffffffff81294bb8>] ? nla_put+0x28/0x40
[  482.058789]  [<ffffffffa0602940>] ? nl80211_send_wiphy+0x3d0/0x2180 [cfg80211]
[  482.058792]  [<ffffffff81294969>] ? nla_parse+0x29/0xc0
[  482.058796]  [<ffffffff813d00b4>] ? rtnl_newlink+0x394/0x5d0
[  482.058800]  [<ffffffff813e6e3b>] ? netlink_dump+0x11b/0x230
[  482.058804]  [<ffffffff813ccd4e>] ? rtnetlink_rcv_msg+0x8e/0x250
[  482.058808]  [<ffffffff813b5cfe>] ? __skb_recv_datagram+0xfe/0x4c0
[  482.058811]  [<ffffffff813b0703>] ? __alloc_skb+0x43/0x2a0
[  482.058815]  [<ffffffff813cccc0>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x30/0x30
[  482.058818]  [<ffffffff813e96f9>] ? netlink_rcv_skb+0xa9/0xc0
[  482.058822]  [<ffffffff813cccaf>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x1f/0x30
[  482.058825]  [<ffffffff813e8d1a>] ? netlink_unicast+0xca/0x1a0
[  482.058828]  [<ffffffff813e910a>] ? netlink_sendmsg+0x31a/0x750
[  482.058832]  [<ffffffff813a8036>] ? sock_sendmsg+0x86/0xc0
[  482.058836]  [<ffffffff813a7d64>] ? move_addr_to_kernel.part.16+0x14/0x60
[  482.058839]  [<ffffffff813a8843>] ? ___sys_sendmsg+0x3c3/0x3d0
[  482.058844]  [<ffffffff8119fa4d>] ? __inode_wait_for_writeback+0x6d/0xc0
[  482.058849]  [<ffffffff81096f80>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x30/0x30
[  482.058853]  [<ffffffff814aa961>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1d1/0x500
[  482.058857]  [<ffffffff8117b278>] ? __fput+0x148/0x210
[  482.058861]  [<ffffffff813a8eb9>] ? __sys_sendmsg+0x39/0x70
[  482.058865]  [<ffffffff814aeb79>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[  482.058883] INFO: task ifconfig:2765 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  482.058962]       Tainted: G           O 3.13-1-amd64 #1
[  482.059037] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  482.059127] ifconfig        D ffff880252627350     0  2765   2713 0x00000004
[  482.059131]  ffff880252627010 0000000000000082 0000000000014280 0000000000014280
[  482.059135]  ffff880250b13fd8 ffff880252627010 ffffffff81887b60 ffff880250b13df0
[  482.059138]  ffffffff81887b64 ffff880252627010 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81887b68
[  482.059141] Call Trace:
[  482.059146]  [<ffffffff814a45d0>] ? schedule_preempt_disabled+0x20/0x70
[  482.059149]  [<ffffffff814a6043>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x133/0x1b0
[  482.059155]  [<ffffffff81188980>] ? path_openat+0x100/0x670
[  482.059158]  [<ffffffff814a60d6>] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x25
[  482.059162]  [<ffffffff813d3055>] ? dev_ioctl+0x365/0x5d0
[  482.059165]  [<ffffffff813a534d>] ? sock_do_ioctl+0x3d/0x50
[  482.059169]  [<ffffffff813a5798>] ? sock_ioctl+0x1e8/0x2c0
[  482.059172]  [<ffffffff8118b94f>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x2cf/0x4a0
[  482.059175]  [<ffffffff8118bba0>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x80/0xa0
[  482.059179]  [<ffffffff814aeb79>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[  482.059183] INFO: task ip:2897 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  482.059260]       Tainted: G           O 3.13-1-amd64 #1
[  482.059337] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  482.059427] ip              D ffff880250299350     0  2897   2896 0x00000000
[  482.059439]  ffff880250299010 0000000000000082 0000000000014280 0000000000014280
[  482.059443]  ffff880036debfd8 ffff880250299010 ffffffff81887b60 ffff880036debba0
[  482.059446]  ffffffff81887b64 ffff880250299010 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81887b68
[  482.059450] Call Trace:
[  482.059454]  [<ffffffff814a45d0>] ? schedule_preempt_disabled+0x20/0x70
[  482.059457]  [<ffffffff814a6043>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x133/0x1b0
[  482.059461]  [<ffffffff814a60d6>] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x25
[  482.059465]  [<ffffffff813ccca0>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x10/0x30
[  482.059468]  [<ffffffff813e8d1a>] ? netlink_unicast+0xca/0x1a0
[  482.059472]  [<ffffffff813e910a>] ? netlink_sendmsg+0x31a/0x750
[  482.059475]  [<ffffffff813a8036>] ? sock_sendmsg+0x86/0xc0
[  482.059479]  [<ffffffff813a7d64>] ? move_addr_to_kernel.part.16+0x14/0x60
[  482.059483]  [<ffffffff813a8843>] ? ___sys_sendmsg+0x3c3/0x3d0
[  482.059486]  [<ffffffff8119fa4d>] ? __inode_wait_for_writeback+0x6d/0xc0
[  482.059490]  [<ffffffff81096f80>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x30/0x30
[  482.059493]  [<ffffffff814aa961>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1d1/0x500
[  482.059498]  [<ffffffff8118ef65>] ? dentry_kill+0x1d5/0x230
[  482.059501]  [<ffffffff8118f014>] ? dput+0x54/0xf0
[  482.059504]  [<ffffffff8117b278>] ? __fput+0x148/0x210
[  482.059508]  [<ffffffff813a8eb9>] ? __sys_sendmsg+0x39/0x70
[  482.059512]  [<ffffffff814aeb79>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[  602.106145] INFO: task ntpd:2267 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  602.106239]       Tainted: G           O 3.13-1-amd64 #1
[  602.106316] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  602.106408] ntpd            D ffff8802519c9350     0  2267      1 0x00000004
[  602.106413]  ffff8802519c9010 0000000000000082 0000000000014280 0000000000014280
[  602.106418]  ffff880251addfd8 ffff8802519c9010 ffffffff81887b60 ffff880251addc80
[  602.106421]  ffffffff81887b64 ffff8802519c9010 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81887b68
[  602.106425] Call Trace:
[  602.106438]  [<ffffffff814a45d0>] ? schedule_preempt_disabled+0x20/0x70
[  602.106442]  [<ffffffff814a6043>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x133/0x1b0
[  602.106446]  [<ffffffff814a60d6>] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x25
[  602.106453]  [<ffffffff813ccca0>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x10/0x30
[  602.106458]  [<ffffffff813e8d1a>] ? netlink_unicast+0xca/0x1a0
[  602.106461]  [<ffffffff813e910a>] ? netlink_sendmsg+0x31a/0x750
[  602.106467]  [<ffffffff813a8036>] ? sock_sendmsg+0x86/0xc0
[  602.106470]  [<ffffffff813e8301>] ? netlink_insert+0x131/0x220
[  602.106474]  [<ffffffff813a81a1>] ? SYSC_sendto+0xf1/0x180
[  602.106478]  [<ffffffff813a51ea>] ? sock_alloc_file+0x9a/0x130
[  602.106483]  [<ffffffff811950d5>] ? __fd_install+0x15/0x40
[  602.106488]  [<ffffffff814aeb79>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b</code>

    Linux deb 3.13-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.13.10-1 (2014-04-15) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

#### syslog

```
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058169]       Tainted: G           O 3.13-1-amd64 #1
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058244] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058336] ntpd            D ffff8802519c9350     0  2267      1 0x00000004
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058341]  ffff8802519c9010 0000000000000082 0000000000014280 0000000000014280
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058346]  ffff880251addfd8 ffff8802519c9010 ffffffff81887b60 ffff880251addc80
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058352]  ffffffff81887b64 ffff8802519c9010 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81887b68
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058359] Call Trace:
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058373]  [<ffffffff814a45d0>] ? schedule_preempt_disabled+0x20/0x70
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058378]  [<ffffffff814a6043>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x133/0x1b0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058382]  [<ffffffff814a60d6>] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x25
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058388]  [<ffffffff813ccca0>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x10/0x30
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058393]  [<ffffffff813e8d1a>] ? netlink_unicast+0xca/0x1a0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058396]  [<ffffffff813e910a>] ? netlink_sendmsg+0x31a/0x750
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058402]  [<ffffffff813a8036>] ? sock_sendmsg+0x86/0xc0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058405]  [<ffffffff813e8301>] ? netlink_insert+0x131/0x220
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058408]  [<ffffffff813a81a1>] ? SYSC_sendto+0xf1/0x180
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058413]  [<ffffffff813a51ea>] ? sock_alloc_file+0x9a/0x130
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058417]  [<ffffffff811950d5>] ? __fd_install+0x15/0x40
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058423]  [<ffffffff814aeb79>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058427] INFO: task NetworkManager:2486 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058507]       Tainted: G           O 3.13-1-amd64 #1
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058582] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058672] NetworkManager  D ffff88024ff1bb40     0  2486      1 0x00000000
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058676]  ffff88024ff1b800 0000000000000086 0000000000014280 0000000000014280
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058680]  ffff8800373d3fd8 ffff88024ff1b800 ffffffff81887b60 ffff8800373d36f0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058683]  ffffffff81887b64 ffff88024ff1b800 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81887b68
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058687] Call Trace:
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058691]  [<ffffffff814a45d0>] ? schedule_preempt_disabled+0x20/0x70
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058695]  [<ffffffff814a6043>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x133/0x1b0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058705]  [<ffffffff814a60d6>] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x25
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058718]  [<ffffffffa06c582a>] ? ieee80211_unregister_hw+0x4a/0x110 [mac80211]
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058726]  [<ffffffffa078f163>] ? brcms_remove+0x43/0x70 [brcmsmac]
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058733]  [<ffffffffa0791181>] ? brcms_ops_start+0x2b1/0x310 [brcmsmac]
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058744]  [<ffffffffa05e9d5b>] ? cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call+0x3db/0x600 [cfg80211]
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058756]  [<ffffffffa06d7ce1>] ? ieee80211_do_open+0x2d1/0xd90 [mac80211]
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058761]  [<ffffffff813c1ae6>] ? __dev_open+0xa6/0x120
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058764]  [<ffffffff813c1da1>] ? __dev_change_flags+0x91/0x160
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058768]  [<ffffffff813c1e8e>] ? dev_change_flags+0x1e/0x60
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058771]  [<ffffffff813cee32>] ? do_setlink+0x312/0x980
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058776]  [<ffffffff81294b7c>] ? __nla_put+0xc/0x20
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058779]  [<ffffffff81294bb8>] ? nla_put+0x28/0x40
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058789]  [<ffffffffa0602940>] ? nl80211_send_wiphy+0x3d0/0x2180 [cfg80211]
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058792]  [<ffffffff81294969>] ? nla_parse+0x29/0xc0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058796]  [<ffffffff813d00b4>] ? rtnl_newlink+0x394/0x5d0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058800]  [<ffffffff813e6e3b>] ? netlink_dump+0x11b/0x230
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058804]  [<ffffffff813ccd4e>] ? rtnetlink_rcv_msg+0x8e/0x250
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058808]  [<ffffffff813b5cfe>] ? __skb_recv_datagram+0xfe/0x4c0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058811]  [<ffffffff813b0703>] ? __alloc_skb+0x43/0x2a0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058815]  [<ffffffff813cccc0>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x30/0x30
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058818]  [<ffffffff813e96f9>] ? netlink_rcv_skb+0xa9/0xc0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058822]  [<ffffffff813cccaf>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x1f/0x30
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058825]  [<ffffffff813e8d1a>] ? netlink_unicast+0xca/0x1a0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058828]  [<ffffffff813e910a>] ? netlink_sendmsg+0x31a/0x750
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058832]  [<ffffffff813a8036>] ? sock_sendmsg+0x86/0xc0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058836]  [<ffffffff813a7d64>] ? move_addr_to_kernel.part.16+0x14/0x60
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058839]  [<ffffffff813a8843>] ? ___sys_sendmsg+0x3c3/0x3d0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058844]  [<ffffffff8119fa4d>] ? __inode_wait_for_writeback+0x6d/0xc0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058849]  [<ffffffff81096f80>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x30/0x30
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058853]  [<ffffffff814aa961>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1d1/0x500
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058857]  [<ffffffff8117b278>] ? __fput+0x148/0x210
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058861]  [<ffffffff813a8eb9>] ? __sys_sendmsg+0x39/0x70
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058865]  [<ffffffff814aeb79>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058883] INFO: task ifconfig:2765 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.058962]       Tainted: G           O 3.13-1-amd64 #1
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059037] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059127] ifconfig        D ffff880252627350     0  2765   2713 0x00000004
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059131]  ffff880252627010 0000000000000082 0000000000014280 0000000000014280
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059135]  ffff880250b13fd8 ffff880252627010 ffffffff81887b60 ffff880250b13df0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059138]  ffffffff81887b64 ffff880252627010 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81887b68
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059141] Call Trace:
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059146]  [<ffffffff814a45d0>] ? schedule_preempt_disabled+0x20/0x70
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059149]  [<ffffffff814a6043>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x133/0x1b0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059155]  [<ffffffff81188980>] ? path_openat+0x100/0x670
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059158]  [<ffffffff814a60d6>] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x25
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059162]  [<ffffffff813d3055>] ? dev_ioctl+0x365/0x5d0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059165]  [<ffffffff813a534d>] ? sock_do_ioctl+0x3d/0x50
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059169]  [<ffffffff813a5798>] ? sock_ioctl+0x1e8/0x2c0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059172]  [<ffffffff8118b94f>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x2cf/0x4a0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059175]  [<ffffffff8118bba0>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x80/0xa0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059179]  [<ffffffff814aeb79>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059183] INFO: task ip:2897 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059260]       Tainted: G           O 3.13-1-amd64 #1
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059337] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059427] ip              D ffff880250299350     0  2897   2896 0x00000000
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059439]  ffff880250299010 0000000000000082 0000000000014280 0000000000014280
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059443]  ffff880036debfd8 ffff880250299010 ffffffff81887b60 ffff880036debba0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059446]  ffffffff81887b64 ffff880250299010 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81887b68
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059450] Call Trace:
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059454]  [<ffffffff814a45d0>] ? schedule_preempt_disabled+0x20/0x70
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059457]  [<ffffffff814a6043>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x133/0x1b0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059461]  [<ffffffff814a60d6>] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x25
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059465]  [<ffffffff813ccca0>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x10/0x30
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059468]  [<ffffffff813e8d1a>] ? netlink_unicast+0xca/0x1a0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059472]  [<ffffffff813e910a>] ? netlink_sendmsg+0x31a/0x750
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059475]  [<ffffffff813a8036>] ? sock_sendmsg+0x86/0xc0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059479]  [<ffffffff813a7d64>] ? move_addr_to_kernel.part.16+0x14/0x60
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059483]  [<ffffffff813a8843>] ? ___sys_sendmsg+0x3c3/0x3d0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059486]  [<ffffffff8119fa4d>] ? __inode_wait_for_writeback+0x6d/0xc0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059490]  [<ffffffff81096f80>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x30/0x30
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059493]  [<ffffffff814aa961>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1d1/0x500
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059498]  [<ffffffff8118ef65>] ? dentry_kill+0x1d5/0x230
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059501]  [<ffffffff8118f014>] ? dput+0x54/0xf0
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059504]  [<ffffffff8117b278>] ? __fput+0x148/0x210
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059508]  [<ffffffff813a8eb9>] ? __sys_sendmsg+0x39/0x70
May  3 10:52:04 deb kernel: [  482.059512]  [<ffffffff814aeb79>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106145] INFO: task ntpd:2267 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106239]       Tainted: G           O 3.13-1-amd64 #1
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106316] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106408] ntpd            D ffff8802519c9350     0  2267      1 0x00000004
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106413]  ffff8802519c9010 0000000000000082 0000000000014280 0000000000014280
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106418]  ffff880251addfd8 ffff8802519c9010 ffffffff81887b60 ffff880251addc80
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106421]  ffffffff81887b64 ffff8802519c9010 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81887b68
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106425] Call Trace:
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106438]  [<ffffffff814a45d0>] ? schedule_preempt_disabled+0x20/0x70
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106442]  [<ffffffff814a6043>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x133/0x1b0
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106446]  [<ffffffff814a60d6>] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x25
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106453]  [<ffffffff813ccca0>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x10/0x30
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106458]  [<ffffffff813e8d1a>] ? netlink_unicast+0xca/0x1a0
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106461]  [<ffffffff813e910a>] ? netlink_sendmsg+0x31a/0x750
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106467]  [<ffffffff813a8036>] ? sock_sendmsg+0x86/0xc0
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106470]  [<ffffffff813e8301>] ? netlink_insert+0x131/0x220
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106474]  [<ffffffff813a81a1>] ? SYSC_sendto+0xf1/0x180
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106478]  [<ffffffff813a51ea>] ? sock_alloc_file+0x9a/0x130
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106483]  [<ffffffff811950d5>] ? __fd_install+0x15/0x40
May  3 10:54:04 deb kernel: [  602.106488]  [<ffffffff814aeb79>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

Comment: It's called **Testing** for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the driver for the wireless is having issues.

I'm not aware of a fix for this but you can try it by either disabling network-manager (boot in single user and disable the init script) or disabling the wireless card from (e.g.) bios before network-manager starts.

These kind of point to the problem:

```
[  482.058718]  [<ffffffffa06c582a>] ? ieee80211_unregister_hw+0x4a/0x110 [mac80211]
[  482.058726]  [<ffffffffa078f163>] ? brcms_remove+0x43/0x70 [brcmsmac]
[  482.058733]  [<ffffffffa0791181>] ? brcms_ops_start+0x2b1/0x310 [brcmsmac]
```

Almost certainly the problem lies within brcmsmac which is a broadcom driver.

You can also try booting with an older kernel or upgrading the bcm firmware (firmware-brcm80211 ?)

Answer (score 3):

These are the key lines:

```
[  362.010382] INFO: task NetworkManager:2486 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  362.010462]       Tainted: G           O 3.13-1-amd64 #1
[  362.010538] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

It tells you that the kernel is unable to communicate with the network hardware. There are several possible reasons for this:

1. **The hardware is broken.** Test by running a different OS on the same hardware, such as a [Fedora Live CD](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedoraLiveCD).
2. **The hardware is working, but disabled.** Laptops often have a key, key combination, or dedicated switch that will turn off the wireless interface. Turn it back on if so.
3. **The kernel has a driver for your network device *family*, but not the particular *model* in your laptop.** Test by [booting into single user mode](https://wiki.debian.org/RunLevel). The network doesn't normally start in single user mode, so if this works, it tells you that the only thing wrong is the networking subsystem, or the way your OS's kernel talks to it.

   What you do next if this is the case is really up to you. You could choose to disable the wireless network in the Debian configuration, using it only for wired networks. You could try a different OS or kernel, with newer drivers. You could try to debug the problem, so that the driver gets fixed.

Comment: I think problem is with my network, because when i enter ifconfig command nothing happened and terminal is stuck. I tested it. Thanks for answer

Comment: When you run `ifconfig`, that causes the kernel to try talking to the driver, which we already knew was having a problem from your test. This only confirms it. The next step is to try a different driver, as with a much different version of Linux. (That's the only reason I suggested Fedora -- purely to be different from Debian.)